# Go Cart template installation

Tags: codeigniter, templates, installation, e-commerce, product

Hi i am trying to use Go Cart e-commerce which is built in Codeigniter. I successfully installed it in localhost. But when i added categories and products only description is showing in front page but no images. Same with the banner. No added them but no image is showing there. I want to use default template. How can i use default template without any problem? Please let me know if someone have any idea. Thank you in advance. Here is the link for Go Cart : https://demo.gocartdv.com

Comment: Have you [asked the author](https://gocartdv.com/page/contact-us) if that was a bug at first place?

Comment: I have solved the Banner issues. They are using short tag for banner and product catalog,but now facing problem with product image. Its not saving product right now. I have trying to solve it.